# Can a way in R be found out to do permutation for objects

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I want to do

```
am<-0
an<-0
bm<-0
bn<-0
cm<-0
cn<-0
.....
.....
```

and son on till zn.Is there a way to do it without writing so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use assign to create variable by name:

```
for (first in  letters[1:3]) {
    for (second in  letters[13:14]) {
        assign(paste(first, second, sep=""), 0)
    }
 }
```

Probably a better way would be to use dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    name=paste(rep(letters[1:3], each=2), rep(letters[13:14], 3), sep=""),
    value=0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already defined you am,an,... as a separate variable , one way to aggregate them in a vector is :

```
vars <- unlist(mget(ls(pattern='^[a-z](m|n)$')))
```

Then it is easy to initialize your vector like this :

```
vars <- 0
```